# why IrreversibleMigration occurs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

The error shows this code can not rollback:

```
class AddCountToTag < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        change_table :tags do |t|
            t.integer :count
            t.index :count
        end
    end
end
```

Where is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`change_table` is not supported yet for reversible migrations. [See this comment at the top of the file](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration/command_recorder.rb) (quoted below) :

```
# <tt>ActiveRecord::Migration::CommandRecorder</tt> records commands done during
    # a migration and knows how to reverse those commands. The CommandRecorder
    # knows how to invert the following commands:
    #
    # * add_column
    # * add_index
    # * add_timestamps
    # * create_table
    # * create_join_table
    # * remove_timestamps
    # * rename_column
    # * rename_index
    # * rename_table
```

If you need to be able to reverse,  you can use `add_column` instead of `change_table`:

```
class AddCountToTag < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        add_column :tags, :count, :integer
        ...
    end
end
```

Comment: ...I have thought change_table was the same as create_table..thank you!!